# A question on notation and a particular step in the analysis of Apollonius Prop 108

Tags: analysis, geometry, notation

I am studying an analysis of the following lemma:

"Given a circle and two points D, E within it, to draw straight lines thought D, E to a point A on the circumference in such a way that, if they meet the circle again in B, C, BC shall be parallel to DE."

Heath (A History of Greek Mathematics, vol. 2), offers the following analysis.

1. Suppose the problem solved and DA, EA drawn ('inflected') to A in such a way that, if AD, AE meet the circle again in B, C, BC is parallel to DE.
2. Draw the tangent at B meeting ED produced in F.
3. Then angle FBD = angle ACB = angle AED
4. Therefore, A, E, B, F are concyclic
5. and consequently FD.DE = AD.DB
6. But the rectangle AD.DB is given, since it depends only on the position of D in relation to the circle, and the circle is given.
7. Therefore the rectangle FD.DE is given.
8. And DE is given; therefore FD is given, and therefore F.
9. It follows that the tangent FB is given in position, and therefore B is given.
10. Therefore BDA is given and consequently AE also.
11. To solve the problem, therefore, we merely take F on ED produced such that FD.DE = the given rectangle made my the segments of any chord through D, draw the tangent FB, join BD and produce it to A, and lastly draw AE through to C; BC is then parallel to DE.

The following diagram is provided as well. I uploaded it to imgur, but can't post it here because I don't have enough reputation points.

[image: Figure]

Now I have two questions:

1. Which further theorems are necessary to deduce step 4 from step 3? The angle at C does not seem to play a role and C is not on the produced circle. So how does the equality of the angles listed in step 3 imply that the points listed in step 4 are concyclic?
2. I don't understand the notations FD.DE and AD.DB. In particular I am confused that Heath, in step 6 and 7, calls AD.DB and FD.DE "rectangles", since the points A, D and B lie on one straight line and so do the points F, D and E. Since the points all lie on one line, no rectangle is given by them.

I appreciate any hints that could shed light on these questions.

All best,
Philipp

Comment: FD.DE means the area of the rectangle with sides FD and DE.

Comment: See [Concyclic points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concyclic_points).

Comment: But FD and DE are segments of one straight line (see the diagram). So there is neither a rectangle nor an area. I am confused about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FD.DE means the area of the rectangle with sides FD and DE. They are two "lenghts", i.e. the lenght of segment FD and DE respectively.

In "ancient" Greek math, *numbers* are only *natural* numbers; thus, a lenght is in general a "magnitude".

The "product" of two lenghts is not a lenght anymore, but a rectangle.

Only with Descartes' [La Géométrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie) the square ot two numbers will be considered a number (see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=MB7F32p0y5MC&pg=PA5)).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Let me see if I got it. We have length FD and length DE. If they are multiplied, we speak of a rectangle, because the multiplication of two lengths is the area of a rectangle. I understand this idiom. However, under this assumption I don't see how the construction in step 11 works. I have two points D and E in a circle. I draw any chord through D. This gives me two lengths (DA and DB) that multiplied with each other equal the multiplication of length DE with length X. So I am looking for X = (DA*DB)/DE. But can this be constructed with compass and straightedge alone?

Comment: Yes, X can be constructed, see for instance [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv3zQ.png).